# Merge with overwrite values from left dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames C and D as follows:

```
C
    A  B
0  AB  1
1  CD  2
2  EF  3

D
    A  B
1  CD  4
2  GH  5
```

I have to merge both the dataframes but the merge should overwrite the values in the right df. Rest of the rows from the dataframe should not change.

```
Output
    A  B
0  AB  1
1  CD  4
2  EF  3
3  GH  5
```

The order of the rows of df must not change i.e. `CD` should remain in index 1. I tried using outer merge which is handling index but duplicating columns instead of overwriting.

```
>>> pd.merge(c,d, how='outer', on='A')
    A  B_x  B_y
0  AB  1.0  NaN
1  CD  2.0  4.0
2  EF  3.0  NaN
3  GH  NaN  5.0
```

Basically B_y should have replaced values in B_x(only where values occur).
I am using Python3.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to replace the rows to override the values in place. This is different from drop duplicates as it will change the ordering of the rows.

Combine DFs takes in "pkey" as an argument, which is the main column on which the merge should happen.

```
def update_df_row(row=None, col_name="", df=pd.DataFrame(), pkey=""):
    try:
        match_index = df.loc[df[pkey] == col_name].index[0]
        row = df.loc[match_index]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    except Exception as ex:
        raise
    finally:
        return row

def combine_dfs(parent_df, child_df, pkey):

    filtered_child_df = child_df[child_df[pkey].isin(parent_df[pkey])]

    parent_df[parent_df[pkey].isin(child_df[pkey])] = parent_df[
        parent_df[pkey].isin(child_df[pkey])].apply(
        lambda row: update_df_row(row, row[pkey], filtered_child_df, pkey), axis=1)

    parent_df = pd.concat([parent_df, child_df]).drop_duplicates([pkey])

    return parent_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

The output of the above code snippet will be:

```
    A   B
0   AD  1
1   CD  4
2   EF  3
3   GH  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = pd.merge(C,D, how='outer', on='A', suffixes=('_',''))

#filter columns names
new_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.endswith('_')]

#remove last char from column names
orig_cols = new_cols.str[:-1]
#dictionary for rename
d = dict(zip(new_cols, orig_cols))

#filter columns and replace NaNs by new appended columns
df[orig_cols] = df[orig_cols].combine_first(df[new_cols].rename(columns=d))
#remove appended columns 
df = df.drop(new_cols, axis=1)
print (df)
    A    B
0  AB  1.0
1  CD  4.0
2  EF  3.0
3  GH  5.0
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. I need to retain the order of the parent df. Just updated the question. Here CD moves to third row.

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to assume that column `A` is in alphabetical order:

```
C = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["AB", "CD", "EF"], "B": [1, 2, 3]})
D = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["CD", "GH"], "B": [4, 5]})
df_merge = pd.concat([C,D]).drop_duplicates('A', keep='last').sort_values(by=['A']).reset_index(drop=True)
df_merge

   A  B
0  AB  1
1  CD  4
2  EF  3
3  GH  5
```

**Edit**

This will do the job if the order in which each category appears in the original dataframes is most important:

```
C = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["AB", "CD", "EF"], "B": [1, 2, 3]})
D = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["CD", "GH"], "B": [4, 5]})
df_merge = pd.concat([C,D]).drop_duplicates('A', keep='last')
df_merge['A'] = pd.Categorical(df_merge['A'], C.A.append(D.A).drop_duplicates())
df_merge.sort_values(by=['A'], inplace=True)
df_merge.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_merge
```

Comment: Sorry but that's not the case

Answer (score 0):

You can use [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas.DataFrame.update). In your case it would be:

```
C.update(D)
```

Comment: This doesn't work since it merges based on the dataframe's index. It replaces the EF row with the GH row entirely, and OP wanted to keep the EF row.